# Is there any way to reassign a value to already defined variable in Karate framework?

Tags: karate

I have a scenario as below: -

```
Scenario: Reassign variable
* def name = "Amod"
* print "Hello " + name
* name = "Animesh"
* print "Hello " + name
```

It gives error below-

```
* name = "Animesh"
no step-definition method match found for: name = "Animesh"
```

To make it work I need to use "def" keyword again. A variable is meant to be declared once and reused & reassigned whenever required. Is it memory efficient to define it every time?

Answer (score 0):

Karate allows you to "overwrite" a variable using `def`. You will see a warning in the console. We don't see any memory issues.